# Rails, how to spot what delete record with multiple associations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I have model with multiple associations:

```
   class ContactsPlacesLink < ActiveRecord::Base
     belongs_to :contact, polymorphic: true, optional: true
     belongs_to :place, polymorphic: true, optional: true
   end

   class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base
     has_many :contacts_places_links, as: :contact, dependent: :delete_all
   end

   class Place < ActiveRecord::Base
     has_many :contacts_places_links, as: :place, dependent: :delete_all
   end
```

Somehow records of `ContactsPlacesLink` is deleted from database, how i can spot what exactly initiate deletion of records and why they are deleted?

Comment: Why do you allow `nil` values on your `belongs_to` association but have `dependent: :delete_all` on the `has_many` at the same time? What is your expected behavior should the `ContactsPlacesLink` remain with `nil` values or do you want them to be deleted? Furthermore, your question is not clear to me: What records get deleted without you noticing? And what do you mean by `event` because there are no events defined in your question?

Comment: @spickermann it's legacy project, agree that `optional: true` and `dependent: :delete_all` at the same time is strange) I will correct main question a bit

Answer (score 0):

If you're debugging locally you could add a temporary `before_destroy` callback to halt the deletion and see the stack trace to determine where it's coming from (Assuming the deletion happens through the ActiveRecord layer).

```
class ContactsPlacesLink < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_destroy { raise "destroy attempted" }
end
```

Comment: i need to find problem in production